# Threading vector sum

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of vectors, say `{{-1, -2}, {-3, -4}, {-5, -2}}`, and I need to add to each of them the vector `{1,2}`.
I tried both with

```
Thread[Plus[{{-1, -2}, {-3, -4}, {-5, -2}}, {1, 2}]]
```

and `MapThread`, but none of them works.

Comment: You can wrap code between Grave accents, or for full line code indent with for spaces. You can highlight code and select the `{}` button to have this done automatically.

Comment: Try `TranslationTransform[{1, 2}] @ {{-1, -2}, {-3, -4}, {-5, -2}}`

Comment: `Plus[{1, 2}, #] & /@ {{-1, -2}, {-3, -4}, {-5, -2}}`

Comment: Both work like a charm, thanks!

Comment: I believe this counts as ["found in the documentation"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html): first example under "Applications". Either that, or this is a duplicate, but my duplicate-searching skills are pretty bad.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Map[Plus[b, #] &, a]

(*  {{0, 0}, {-2, -2}, {-4, 0}}  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work with `Thread`, but you need to specify a few things. From the documentation of [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) you can see that giving  a third argument you can thread over only the first `n` arguments. You can therefore use

```
Thread[f[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, {g, h}], List, 1]
```

which gives

```
In[1] := Thread[f[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, {g, h}], List, 1]
Out[1] = {f[{a, b}, {g, h}], f[{c, d}, {g, h}], f[{e, f}, {g, h}]}
```

Now the only problem is that if you now try it with `Plus` instead of a generic `f` you get the error:

[image: Objects of unequal length cannot be combined]

This happens because `Plus` gets evaluated before `Thread` has the chance to process its first argument.
A way to work around this problem is to use `HoldForm` to force `Plus` to not get evaluated, and than release the hold when Thread is finished:

```
Thread[HoldForm[Plus][{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, {g, h}], List, 1] // ReleaseHold
```

Another way, probably simpler, is to use the form above with a generic `f` (which must not be assigned to anything for this to work) and then replace `f` with `Plus` after `Thread` is done:

```
Thread[foo[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, {g, h}], List, 1] /. foo -> Plus
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
{1, 2} + # & /@ {{-1, -2}, {-3, -4}, {-5, -2}}
```

**Output**

> {{0, 0}, {-2, -2}, {-4, 0}}